# ComboBox QML does not show item text after selection

Tags: qt, combobox, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have a QML ComboBox whose model is defined as a C++ QList < QObject* >.
When I open the drop down list, I can see all items defined in the C++ model, but after selection, the selected item is not shown.
So, items are only visible in the drop down element.
The relevant part of the qml file is:

```
ComboBox {
    id: placesCombo
    anchors.top: parent.top
    width: parent.width
    model: myModel
    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        width: placesCombo.width
        contentItem: Text {
            id: placesComboItem
            text: displayLabel
            elide: Text.ElideRight
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }
    }
}
```

How to display in the closed combobox the item text previously selected in the drop down element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.huihoo.com/qt/5.x/qml-qtquick-controls2-combobox.html#textRole-prop):

> **textRole : string**
>
> This property holds the model role used for
>   populating the combo box.
>
> When the model has multiple roles, textRole can be set to determine
>   which role should be displayed.

You have to indicate the role of the model to be displayed through textRole.

```
ComboBox {
    id: placesCombo
    textRole: "displayLabel"
    ...
}
```